# How can I merge within a nested hashmap?

Tags: clojure

I have a nested hashmap with a structure something like the following:

```
(def pathmap {:order {:genus {:species {:cat2 "data", :cat1 "data"}}}})
```

What I need is a function like assoc-in that will allow me to add new key-value pairs to the innermost nested map rather than simply replacing what's already there. For example:

```
(my-assoc-merge pathmap [:order :genus :species] {:cat3 "data"})
;=> {:order {:genus {:species {:cat3 "data" :cat2 "data", :cat1 "data"}}}}
```

I thought I might be able to do this easily enough by altering the assoc-in function slightly to use merge-with and union:

```
(defn my-assoc-merge
  [m [k & ks] v]
  (if ks
    (assoc m k (my-assoc-merge (get m k) ks v))
    (assoc m k (merge-with clojure.set/union (get m k '{}) v))))
```

Unfortunately this gives me the error "CompilerException java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: count not supported on this type: Keyword, compiling:(core.clj:34:12)". Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, `assoc-in` already creates a new key if it does not exist. Usage is as follows:

```
(def pathmap {:order {:genus {:species {:cat2 "data", :cat1 "data"}}}})

(assoc-in pathmap [:order :genus :species :cat3] "data")
;=> {:order {:genus {:species {:cat2 "data", :cat3 "data", :cat1 "data"}}}}
```

If you prefer to merge a new map, use `update-in` with `merge`

```
(update-in pathmap [:order :genus :species] merge {:cat3 "data"})
;=> {:order {:genus {:species {:cat2 "data", :cat3 "data", :cat1 "data"}}}}
```

The problem with your `my-assoc-merge` is the `union` which works on sets. Change `merge-with` to `merge` and drop the `union`.

Comment: A brilliant function in a brilliant language.

Comment: `update-in` does exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for the correction also.